# how to animate a component by changing its class rather than style?

Tags: css, angular, typescript

Here is an animation example that uses state/style concept:

```
@Component({
animations: [
  trigger('myComponent', [
    state('state1', style({ xxxxx })),
    state('state2', style({ xxxxx })),
    transition('* => *', animate(500))
  ])
]
```

But I need to use a class instead of style, i.e.:

```
@Component({
animations: [
  trigger('myDIV', [
    state('state1', class('col-md-5')),
    state('state2', class('col-md-12')),
    transition('* => *', animate(500))
  ])
]
```

I.e. I want to animate div columns resizing:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5" [@myDIV]>
   <app-component1></app-component1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-7">
   <app-component2></app-component2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Style works fine but not Class. Is there another special approach ?

Thanks

Comment: i dont think you can . Angular 2 animations are built on top of the W3C's CSS3 transitions API

Comment: so how do I implement it another way?